# PHP check in_array number of year

Tags: php

i am trying to make a post user bithyear from data. But i have one question here.

So i want to check the posted year `in_array`. User can choose a year from 1950 to 2017. I used the following php code for it.

```
<select name="birth_year" id="year" class="t1-select">
   <option value="">Year</option>
     <?php  for ($i=1950; $i<date('Y'); $i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
           <?php echo $i; ?>
        </option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Now you know the option values are `1950,1951,1952,...,2014,2015,2016,2017`.

You know user can change the options value from developer consols. That means user can post 100000 . I want to check this numbers of years using php.

I know i can do it with the following array

```
    $birthMonth = array( "1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955",....,"2014,"2016","2017"");

    if(in_array($_POST['birth'], $birthMonth)){}
```

This means i need to write so many number of year. My question is : How can i check posted number of years `in_array` shortly ?

Anyone can help me here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to dynamically build the array of years for you:

```
if(in_array($_POST['birth'], range(1950, date("Y")))){}
```

You can use `date("Y")` to always get the current year. You can always do other date magic to limit it to a certain range like "10 years ago".

```
if(in_array($_POST['birth'], range(1950, date("Y", strtotime('-10 years'))))){}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we can use it for also date write?, like: `if(in_array($_POST['date'], range(01, date("d")))){}`

Comment: Not if you have a leading zero in front of you day. That makes it an octal which is not the same as a decimal number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an `array` for such a simple task, i.e:

```
if(!empty($_POST['birth']))
{
    $bday = $_POST['birth'];
    if ($bday >= 1950 and $bday <= date("Y"))
    {
      # do something
    }
}
```